# A question on solvable groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, solvable-groups

Let's suppose $S$ is a group and can be written as $S= G_1\times G_2\times\cdots\times G_K$; here each $G_i$ is a group of prime power order. And $o(S)= n.$ Is this $S$ solvable group? If yes how will we show that.

Comment: So $\;S\;$ is a direct product of nilpotent groups and thus nilpotent by itself...and thus solvable, too. :)

Comment: Yes, it is. Each $G_i$ is solvable, because the Sylow theorems allow you to produce subgroups whose order is $p^{n-1}$ if $|G_i| = p^n$. Also, the direct product of solvable groups is solvable.

Comment: I got it. Thank you Prahlad and Antonio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: the Sylow theorems guarantee that a group of order $p^n$ has a chain of subgroups $G_0 \subset \dots \subset G_n$, each normal in the next, with $|G_i|=p^i$. This shows that a group of order $p^n$ is solvable. Now demonstrate such a sequence on $S$ by inducting on $K$, the number of prime power factors.

Comment: Evne nicer: without Sylow theorems and simply by induction on $\;n\;$, using the class equation, one can prove that a group of order $\;p^n\;,\;\;p=$ a prime has a **normal** subgroup of order $\;p^k\;,\;\;\forall \,0\le k\le n\;$

Comment: Yeah, even that is more simple. Thank you guys.

Comment: @DonAntonio Good point!